# VBA Before Close

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, powerpoint

Então o que eu quero fazer é ter uma caixa de mensagem que aparece quando este arquivo do PowerPoint tentam fechar, dizendo "Você enviou os dados?" "Sim ou não".

Se clicarem em "Sim", o Excel fecha, se clicarem em "Não", cancela a operação de fechamento.

Eu sou muito novato com VBA, se você me explicar passo a passo, eu agradeceria. Eu tentei este código, mas não funciona:

```
Private Sub PPTApp_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If MsgBox("Text", _

            vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

        Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, Leonardo.

Veja se o código abaixo ajuda, por favor:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = MsgBox("Você enviou os dados?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo
End Sub
```